# Setting volume per instance in QML Audio/Video elements?

Tags: qt, qml

I want to fade out the volume of an audio file while fading in the sound of a video in QML.
This should be no problem with animations, but I'm hitting a wall here.
It seems like the `volume` property is somehow shared between all instances of all media elements in QML. See for example the following code:

```
Rectangle
{
    id:mainScreen
    focus: true

    Video
    {
        id:video
        anchors.fill: parent
        source: "path/to/file.mp4";
        volume:1
        onVolumeChanged: console.warn("video: "+volume)
        autoPlay: true
    }
    Audio
    {
        source: "path/to/file.mp3";
        id:audio
        volume:1
        onVolumeChanged: console.warn("audio: "+volume)
        autoPlay: true
    }


    Keys.onPressed:
    {
        audio.volume = Math.random(1);
    }
}
```

When I press a key, the `onVolumeChanged`-Handlers of both `video` and `audio` are called.
Is there a way to control the volume of the elements independently?

Or should I file a Qt bug report? This is the OpenGL MSVC2010 build of Qt 5.2.0 in case it matters.

Comment: Can you try to do `event.accepted = true;` in your `Keys.onPressed` handler? My guess is that this event is thrown again to some another widget. See http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtquick/qml-qtquick2-keys.html#onPressed-signal  and  http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtquick/qml-qtquick2-keyevent.html#accepted-prop for more information

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't help. Both handlers are still called... Also, this is just a minimal example that demonstrates my problem, in the real code the volume change isn't triggered by mouse input but by some other events.

Comment: No idea than. Btw, you can try to reach some QtQuick developers in the IRC. It definitely can be a bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kakadu, you were right. I hit [this bug](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-30317) and the provided patch fixes it!
With that patch, everything works as-is.